# Исключение слова в preg_match_all

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть задача найти все вхождения текстов в  исключая одно слово.
Нахожу таким способом:

```
preg_match_all(/<div>(.*?)<\/div>/is, $html, $matches);
```

Находит:

```
<div>текст1</div> -> текст1
<div>текст2</div> -> текст2
<div>текст3</div> -> текст3
```

А вот можно, как то исключить слово "текст2" прямо в регулярном выражении, не прибегая к перебору массива?

Answer (score 0):

```
$except = "текст2";
$regex = "/<div>(?!$except)(.*?)<\/div>/is";
$html = "
<div>текст1</div> -> текст1
<div>текст2</div> -> текст2
<div>текст3</div> -> текст3
";
$matches = [];

preg_match_all($regex, $html, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Выведет

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(22) "<div>текст1</div>"
    [1]=>
    string(22) "<div>текст3</div>"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "текст1"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "текст3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Великолепно, то что нужно!  А для общего развития... как сдалать инверсию, т.е. чтобы в matches попал только текст2?

Comment: @dimad77 Как видишь там есть переменная $except. Для регулряного выражения необходимо прописать `(?!слово тут|слово2)` в таком виде, советую изучать регулярные выражения и потестировать их на regex101, поможет разобраться во всем!

Answer (score 0):

Потестировал. В предложенном варианте слово должно быть в начале текста. Вот нашел вариант, где оно может быть в любом месте в контенте DIV:

```
'/<div>((?:(?!текст1).)*?)<\/div>/is'
```

Но вопрос с обратным эффектом остался. Как ОСТАВИТЬ только DIV c "текст1",  а остальные (неизвестное кол-во) отфильтровать?

Comment: Если нужно оставить только текст1, то замените ?! на ?=

Comment: Пробовал, не работает :(